# Noah's Ark Submarine

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, vehicles-transportation, parashat-noach, mabul

Are there any meforshim (commentators) who believe that Noah's ark was a submarine that went under water?

I remember seeing a Seforno on this but don't remember more; it could even be on this site but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ramban 8:5 on the passuk "And the waters slowly receded until the tenth month"](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=1&perek=8&mefaresh=ramban):

והנראה לדעתי בשוט התיבה, כי הייתה מפני היות המים נובעים מן התהומות, והיותם עוד רותחים כדברי רבותינו, כי בעבור כן תלך על פני המים. ואם לא מפני זה הייתה נטבעת בכבדותה כי רבים אשר בתוכה, והמאכל והמשקה היה הרבה מאד. וכאשר שככו המים מנביעתם, או מרתיחתם גם כן, וחסרו ברוח, מיד נכנסה התיבה אל תוך המים בכובד משאה ותנח על ההר:

> Concerning the movement of the Ark in the water, it seems to me that because the water flowed (upwards) from the depths of the earth, and because the waters were still boiling according to Chazal, therefore the Ark moved on the surface of the water. And if not for these factors it would have sunk due to it’s great weight since there were many (people and animals) within it, and there was a great amount of food and drink.
>
> And when the water stopped flowing, or when the boiling also stopped, and the wind caused the waters to recede, the Ark immediately entered the water due to it’s great load, and rested on the mountain.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The Ramban I referenced believes the ark was submerged. I added the relevant text.

Comment: Only for a short time,mostly it was on top of the waters.

Comment: The ark was partially submerged. Like any ship.